# WCF + Entity Framework CodeFirst = DynamicProxies exception?

Tags: wcf-data-services, ef-code-first

I'm trying out EF CodeFirst CTP 5, and using it with WCF Data Services.  I'm getting an error that `Internal Server Error. The type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Person_C321D7A37002A1B42C3CBAECC27983D77F6B7FCC3F837175B2CBB55CCA66AF55' is not a complex type or an entity type.`

If I use an edmx-generated Person off the db created by CF, I have no issue.  In reading up, it seems that the lazy loading is screwing things up, and previous EF versions have let me turn off proxy generation with an option flag that's not present in the DbContext.  There is a way to set up LazyLoading to false, but that doesn't apparently turn off proxy generation.

Thanks.

Comment: can't you eager load the entity relation.

Comment: No, I don't want it to load them at all, since it's an OData feed and it's just dropping links to the other entities anyway. I already set LazyLoadingEnabled = false, so it's not a question of when the things get loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you can do in EF code first CTP5:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Alternatively, this is a bug in WCF data services in VS 2010 RTM. You can used the CTP1 of WCF Data Services that has [this issue](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d8334829-9b77-4ab2-bbdb-d71ceaca57e4&displaylang=en) fixed.

Hope this helps.
Thanks
Pratik

Comment: Just for the record, the CTP1 install did *not* fix the problem but the solution with the cast to IObjectContextAdapter did, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In CTP1, the binaries have been renamed to Microsoft.Data.Services.*.dll. Did you change the references to the new assemblies? I am pretty sure that this issue was fixed in CTP1. So just wanted to make sure it worked for you.

Thanks
Pratik

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new DbContext class, then you can make use of

```
Configuration.ProxyCreation = false
```

To disable the dynamic proxy creation